# Handle query string parameters when multiple values passing

Tags: jquery

Below is my script

```
$("#locSearchSubmitBtn").click(function(){          
        var locname = $("#location").val();
        var qparam = window.location.search.replace(/[\\?&]q=([^&#]*)/g,'')
        history.pushState({},"qparam", '?q='+locname+qparam);
        //alert(locname);
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index,ele) {

            var qparam = window.location.search.replace(/[\\?&]q=([^&#]*)/g,'').replace(/[\\?&]tloc=([^&#]*)/g,'');
            history.pushState({},"qparam", '?q='+locname+qparam+'&tloc='+ele.value);
        });
        $("#specialitycenters li.selected").each(function (index,ele) {
            ele = $(this).text();               
            var qparam = window.location.search.replace(/[\\?&]q=([^&#]*)/g,'').replace(/[\\?&]sc=([^&#]*)/g,'');
            history.pushState({},"qparam", '?q='+locname+qparam+'&sc='+ele);
        });

    });
```

Here I am trying to get the check box checked values and append them to URL.
But I am unable to pass the multiple values if I selected more than one checkboxes.

The URL builds like

```
http://portalauthv2tst:10039/wps/myportal/childrenspublic/testpages/newsearch/?q=&tloc=Hospital_or_ER
```

Here tloc is the parameter which holds the check box value, on second button click, If I chose two checkboxes previous tloc value is removing and new one is appending.

How can I append multiple checkbox values using each function.

Answer (score 0):

```
In javascript, that's just a string:

var url = 'http://example.com/mypage?vendorId=1&vendorId=2&vendorId=3'
var qs = url.split('?')[1];
var parts = qs.split('&');
var arr = [];

$.each(parts, function() {
    var val = this.split('=')[1];
    arr.push(val);
});

FIDDLE

or the short way:

var arr = $.map(window.location.split('?')[1].split('&'), function(e,i) { 
    return e.split('=')[1];
});
```